# Angular 8 PrimeNG 8 Sub menu (Tiered Menu) showing up behind the scroll (overflow)

Tags: css, angular, primeng

here a real problem  menu

[image]

I have a MenuTiered from primeng angular 8. The problem is that when I add scroll, the sub-menu will be behind the scroll. I've added appendTo="body" but that did not help except for correct positioning. I tried also the propertie "autoZIndex" from primeng.

I have tried explicitly setting the z-index but could not override the dynamically generated CSS that is applied to the scroll(overflow).

Bellow  a simple code : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cyvv7d

Any ideas, please?

Comment: did you try `p-tieredMenu { position: absolute }` in css?

Comment: yes, I did. but not working

Comment: worked for me: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8dgayr

Comment: problem when you apply position absotute. A scroll was removed